# Error in hiphop php installation on centos

Tags: php, facebook, hiphop

I had followed the steps of installation from git

I am getting this error when i am building hiphop

i am using centos5x and installed all the dependencies

```
 root@host [~/hiphop/hiphop-php]# cmake .
 -- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was missing, proceeding anyway
 -- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_44
 -- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_44 - Success
 -- Boost version: 1.48.0
 -- Found the following Boost libraries:
 --   system
 --   program_options
--   filesystem
 --   regex
 -- Found LIBGLOG: /usr/lib/libglog.so
 -- Could NOT find LIBINOTIFY (missing:  LIBINOTIFY_LIBRARY)
 -- Found LIBUNWIND: /usr/lib/libunwind.so
 -- Could NOT find LIBICONV (missing:  LIBICONV_LIBRARY)
 -- Performing Test LIBICONV_CONST
 -- Performing Test LIBICONV_CONST - Failed
 -- MySQL Include dir: /usr/include  library dir: /usr/lib64
 -- MySQL client libraries: mysqlclient_r
 -- Found LIBMEMCACHED: /usr/lib/libmemcached.so
 -- Found PCRE: /usr/lib64/libpcre.so
 -- Found libevent: /usr/lib64/libevent.so
 -- Looking for evhttp_bind_socket_with_fd
 -- Looking for evhttp_bind_socket_with_fd - not found
 CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:87 (message):
  Custom libevent is required with HipHop patches
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMake/HPHPSetup.cmake:46 (include)
  hphp/CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)
 enter code here

 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 root@host [~/hiphop/hiphop-php]#
 root@host [~/hiphop/hiphop-php]#
```

please can any one solve this

Answer (score -1):

Here is the detailed installation guide: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki